# Supplying your own needle for Blood test for a Kurdistan residency permit

Tags: health, residency, iraqi-kurdistan

For the blood test (if still required) (see [Current blood test requirement for Kurdistan residency permit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42664/current-blood-test-requirement-for-kurdistan-residency-permit)) can one supply one’s own needle?

Details of what is involved, in medical terms, would also be appreciated.

Comment: I would expect that you can't provide your own needle, because there's no way to guarantee that it hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: @pnuts Why do you want to bring your own needle?

Comment: Question, I think I looked this up when you originally posted but I can't remember - residency permit? You'll know better than me, but shouldn't that be an expats question then, rather than travel? Or does it cover touristy-ness as well?

Comment: @pnuts would you please clarify if you are asking about the Iraqi autonomous province? Or the Irani administered province of Kurdistan?

Comment: @pnuts yeah I looked into it too, it's a weird case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a nationality is not specified and the prerequisites for reaching a border point in Kurdistan are not specified. This information is vital to providing a quality answer.

Comment: @GayotFow shouldn't that be unclear then, not off-topic?

Comment: @MarkMayo you are a trusted user on the site, LOL, you can thus "call 'em as you see 'em". For me it's OT but I agree it can equally be "Unclear"

Answer (score 6):

I watched a BBC  documentary today about some of the battlegrounds used by Alexander the Great.  The narrator had to pass through Kurdistan border control and the procedure was included in the documentary from start to finish.  There was no evidence of a blood test at all.  Here's a screen cap...

[image]

Source:  BBC, fair use

As seen, the control point uses a manual ledger and contains no equipment of any sort.  From this we can safely infer that of course you can use your own needle if you are asked for a blood sample. But I do not see evidence of that situation happening in real life.

Comment: How long ago did that person go through the procedure?

Comment: @JoErNanO, given that the British passports are maroon, we can safely assume it was some time after 1995.

Comment: For sure he was staying for a while, there's a lot of battlefields to cover, but yeah, check it out.  It's a great documentary!