# Do I have to fill out a form when submitting a blood test for a Kurdistan residency permit? If so, what details does it request?

Tags: health, paperwork, residency, iraqi-kurdistan

I'm trying to find out whether or not a blood test is required at present (see: [Do I still need a blood test for a Kurdistan residency permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42664/do-i-still-need-a-blood-test-for-a-kurdistan-residency-permit)).

What does/did the form available from the residence office look like and what details does/did it request?

---

I was asking for information of the details that might be requested in case these included times of and/or locations of visits to other countries, such as those that have been prone to Yellow Fever, Hepatitis, Ebola, Legionnaires', SARS, HIV etc. so that I might assemble that information, together with whatever other information was required, "at my leisure" from data to hand, rather than attempting to provide the information required when in some clinic a long way from my records.

It is certainly possible that no such form exists – judging by @Gayot's [image](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/54251/4995) the Kurdistan Region may not be high tech - however there do seem to be enough tests being carried out to justify a form! (see [Joel Damien](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/69406/4995)).

Since it is the information required for the form that is of interest to me by *Do I have to fill out a form* I mean either by myself or with someone else wielding writing instrument/machine.

---

Some details from [NGO Coordinating Committee for Iraq](http://www.ncciraq.org/en/about/about-iraq/iraqi-visa-procedures) from September 2015:

> Blood tests – The test will check for the following: HIV, HCV Antibody, HBs Antigen, Malaria and Bilharzia first you must go to the residency office with a color copy of the picture page of your passport and one passport-sized photo. Take this to Office 21 in the main courtyard on the ground floor and they will give you a paper to take to the hospital to authorize your blood test. The blood test can be taken at the Hawler Teaching Hospital (Safeen, Arbil  36.199296, 44.019706) in Shorish District, located on the street between Jalil Khayat Mosque and Royal Mall to the North and the taxi garage for Duhok/Soran to the south. The test costs 31 500 IQD and results are available for collection after two working days from office 21 at the residency office.

It seems possible details may be required by both "Office 21" and the hospital.

Comment: I know this is late, and I may have asked in the chat, but residency? That sounds like moving for work.  Also, have you done it, and if so, do you maybe have an answer?

Comment: I've emailed a group that organises it for the Ministry of the Interior, let's see if we have any luck anyway :)

Comment: yeah I've assumed it is (from my research) and have asked if they can send me a copy of such a form. We'll see.

Comment: stupid mail returned undeliverable....sigh

Comment: I don't think a state in the middle of a war is going to be consistent with such minutiae details. You're probably going to be one of the few hundred tourists per year, so thry might not even have any forms printed in the first place.

Comment: Never mind then.

Comment: I just spotted this question now. I have visited Kurdistan about roughly 3 years back and stayed for just over 15 days. I did not take any blood test. However, I did visit some kind of office during my stay. I went as a tourist and visited my dad who was there for a few years. Will add another comment after I find out from him.

Comment: Ok so not sure how much of a help I can be here, I had a chat with my dad and he says a blood test is DEFINITELY required if you are going there for any other purpose other than tourism. He does not recollect filling up any forms but you need to go to some sort of a local Govt Medical Center to get your test done. He also had a reliable local contact there and he believes this contact expedited all formalities.

Comment: So in any case if you dont speak the local language, you are definitely allowed to use an appropriate person to assist you with the formalities. My dad also believes these formalities are independent of nationalities. So, usually everybody who goes there gets it done if you are staying for a relatively long period of time.

Comment: Re: details from September 2015. Are you sure that the form is filled out by the traveler rather than by the hospital? It sounds like you will get a form with a list of diseases and the hospital will tick off "negative" (hopefully) next to each.

Comment: Well yes, but here the word "form" probably refers to a piece of paper that says "check person X for diseases A, B, C". Not something you actually fill out.

Answer (score 3):

From searching, one thing is certain, **there is indeed a [form](http://www.krgspain.org/english-residence/)**.

> Evidence that the applicant has undertaken a blood test according to
>   the procedures of the residence office. **A form to obtain a blood test
>   appointment can be collected from the residence office as part of the
>   application process.** The blood test result can usually be obtained
>   within 2-3 days.

You have to collect it from one of the [residence offices](https://web.archive.org/web/20160325042309/http://erbilresidency.com/erbilairport.php) when you make your application. This [travel account](http://www.wanderingearl.com/visiting-the-directorate-of-residence-in-kurdistan/) is 5 years old, but it relates a visit to the Directorate of Residence in Erbil and it seems they do have computers, so it's likely the form will end up computerized.

<sub>Research still ongoing as to what exactly is on the form, will complete if/when I find more.</sub>

Comment: @pnuts the erbilresidency website is in maintenance, I'll update this A when it's up. The last [snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20160402192935/http://erbilresidency.com/shortterm.php) of it mentions 15 days, and the [US](http://www.krg.us/services/visa-2/) representation says 14 days, and so does the [State Dept](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/iraq.html)

Answer (score 2):

According to KRG guidelines, anyone travelling to Kurdistan is required to include an evidence of the blood test undertaken with the application.

You will have to obtain a form for the blood test and then make an appointment with the residence office. Remember that the KRG guidlines say that obtaining blood test form and conducting the test is part of the whole **application process**.

It normally takes 2 to 3 days to get the blood test results.

The blood test requirements are for all types of travellers both short term and long term.

There is a detailed advice on the official Website of KRG.

Comment: Do you have a link to the official website of KRG?